# How to get a unique identifier of the computer?

Tags: java, c++, c, windows, java-native-interface

I'm writing a game server in Java and I need a way to get a unique identifier for a computer (Multiaccount protection), target platform is Windows >= XP. I tested many ways to do it with pure Java and JNI:

- MAC Address - Very easy to change, high collision chance
- (JNI) Motherboard SN - It is not always, high collision chance
- (JNI) Diskdrive SN - Can't detect disk drive by disk letter with WMI, little collision chance, doesn't work on Windows XP (Hasn't SerialNumber field)
- File in hidden folder - Doesn't saves after Windows reinstall, can modify or delete if i know where it.
- (JNI) Windows GUID - high collision chance, doesn't saves after Windows Reinstall.

Any another way?

Comment: If you're writing in Java, why are there the tags for c++ & c?!

Comment: @IosifM. He may write native code, in c/c++.

Comment: fair enuff... didn't know

Comment: By the way, you should avoid putting "Best way" in the title as this leads to it being voted to close as opinionated.

Comment: You call mac address high collision chance with 2^48 combinations, how many players do you think your games going to have?

Comment: Can you do it the steam way?  a named account that can only be logged in once?

Comment: Any user can set any MAC address.

Comment: Yes. One account = One computer.

Comment: Being able to set it doesn't make it high collision chance though.

Comment: It'd be better if you gave more info. When you say "multiaccount protection", do you mean that you want to restrict players/computers from logging in with multiple accounts? Can you also clarify, if the user reinstalls the OS, should it be "the same computer"? What if the motherboard is moved? If the answer to these kinds of questions is no, then how about a combination of two or more of the methods you mentioned?

Comment: It's makes. And without change i has many users with same MAC.

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis, e.g. DiskDrive serial number saves after reinstall. It's changable, but more difficult.

Comment: Just understand that your never going to have a 'perfect' method of checking if a pc is the same, any detail your checking can either change through the user changing something digital or replacing hardware. This is why systems like SecuRom allow multiple installs but you must deregister your computer between each. The only thing that would survive most of this is a rootkit, but those aren't what you want to be using. Perhaps you should design your system so that a user logs in with their account and it only allows them to pass if their mobo s/n matches stored, closer to how steam operates.

Comment: Yes, but how frequent users change their computer details?

Comment: There is no perfect solution since one could easily create some virtual machines and thus change all of these parameters.

Comment: Not all users has experience to set VM. And not all VMs has hardware graphic acceleration.

Comment: Running a credit card and storing the user's billing address? It'd be pretty effective!

Comment: @exabrial, game is free =) And i can enter any billing address =)

Comment: Oh haha... yah that would slow your uptake rate. uh dna blood sample? J/K

Comment: Just so i get this straight. In case a user has multiple computer at home (e.g. i have a desktop and a laptop, because i move to a dorm during the week and i'm home during weekends) that means a user can run the game from only one computer (so if i'm home and i don't wanna unpack my laptop i can't play on my desktop?) and never from another? Why would you limit a user to something like that? Or to prevent being logged in on the same machine on two accounts at once?

Comment: Because e.g. if server administrator banned a player, it will not play on this server again =) And you can play on laptop from desktop account.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you to use CPUID I ve used it to my software licensing

Cheers :)

Comment: But CPUID can only has two values: GenuineIntel or AuthenticAMD

Comment: It has a lot more than that - take a look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID)

Comment: But it still not unique

Answer (score 0):

There is not really any way to get the unique identifier of the computer. Many programmers apply different logic and different things but any of the logic or system is not full proof. Thus, you have to create a logic which is not easily broken by other programmers easily. As you are trying create Game Server and thus you have to try different logic and best thing unique I have found are:

- You can have the IP Address of the User
- User MAC Address
- User Email Address
- Users HDD Serial Number
- User Motherboard Name and Number

You have to create the your combination along with some hash to mix thus the Key remains unique for every computer

Comment: Please, fully read my question!
1) Many users uses NAT or dynamic IP
2) MAC Address is unsafe
3) Email is changable, and has services who provide one-time emails
4) Can change, not globally unique
5) Not always has